# How do we get Robin D. Laws to use and promote this site?

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-promotion

[C. Ross](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/users/45/c-ross)'s question [How should we promote this site](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173/how-should-we-promote-this-site) got me thinking. One of the reasons that StackOverflow was initially so successful was due to the large followings that Joel Spolsky and Jeff Atwood brought to the site. Therefore, I think it would be great if we could have a well known expert with a large following using this site.

The first person that came to my mind was [Robin D. Laws](http://robin-d-laws.livejournal.com/). He has been mentioned in several answers already.

- [What role-playing games have the best gamemaster advice sections?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/791/what-role-playing-games-have-the-best-gamemaster-advice-sections#826)
- [What is the single most influential book every GM should read?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1113/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-gm-should-read#1118)
- [Encouraging out-of-the-box thinking in-game.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/975/encouraging-out-of-the-box-thinking-in-game#978)

So how do go about getting him involved?

Answer (score 6):

Once we're in public beta, the easiest answer, to me, is to simply e-mail or Livejournal private message him and let him know about this site, its mission, and graciously state that we'd love to see him as a member of our community. No hard sell, just something he may be interested in.

Comment: So we're in public beta... who's got the courage to email him?

Comment: It should probably be someone who already comments enough on his LiveJournal to be somewhat "recognized."

Comment: Oi. Additionally, we should link to his [LiveJournal](http://robin-d-laws.livejournal.com/) directly; all (non-meta) mentions of him only link to PDFs and not-Robin's site. If linking to his site sends enough traffic his way, he may check referrals and stumble upon us naturally.

Answer (score 4):

Robin's a full-time freelancer, so he's more likely to use the site if it has value to him. If the site winds up seeing a lot of design questions that are asked and answered well, I suspect it'll have more utility for any and all professionals. Let us continue to avoid the artificiality that comes with seeding, but if anyone has any design questions they need answered, we might well give them a shot.