# Questions worth Sharing?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

In response to [Bryant's excellent idea](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173/how-should-we-promote-this-site/303#303) for [promoting the site](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173/how-should-we-promote-this-site), what are some *exemplary* questions that are worth sharing on social media?

The question should have:

- No Close Votes
- At least one answer
- At least one upvote.

So what questions should I be liking on Stumble?

Comment: A note - probably the better ones to put out there on digg/reddit are going to be ones with more non-game-wonk appeal...  The WWZ one is a good one IMO, but ones about complex rules interactions will be met with quizzical stares from the Internet at large.

Comment: @mxyzplk Specific ones are OK on stumble.  They get tagged RPG and only gamers will see them.

Comment: Even so, there's specific and then there's way too specific.  Vote/submit what you want, I'm just saying that rules minutiae won't get much interest, and that it might be a good idea to concentrate on ones with wider appeal.  YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

I'm taking this as a one-suggestion-per-answer thing so people can up-vote. In deemed inappropriate, I'll merge my answers later.

[What RPG best models a “World War Z” zombie apocalypse?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1779/what-rpg-best-models-a-world-war-z-zombie-apocalypse)

Comment: I've Stumbled this one.

Answer (score 2):

I'm taking this as a one-suggestion-per-answer thing so people can up-vote. In deemed inappropriate, I'll merge my answers later.

[How to keep track of abilities for D&D 4e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109/how-to-keep-track-of-abilities-for-dd-4e/119)

Comment: Stumbled (2010-08-08)

Answer (score 2):

You could/should just digg/stumble upon the home page of this site :P

I think it's pretty cool all on its own :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking this as a one-suggestion-per-answer thing so people can up-vote. In deemed inappropriate, I'll merge my answers later.

[A medusa and a beholder look at each other. What happens?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/526/a-medusa-and-a-beholder-look-at-each-other-what-happens/544)

Answer (score 1):

[Playing 4th Ed D&D for the first time, what should I read to avoid holding everyone back.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/419/playing-4th-ed-dd-for-the-first-time-what-should-i-read-to-avoid-holding-everyo)

I've stumbled this already.  (Just FYI, stumble works best if multiple people stumble the same site).  I submitted it August 29th.  Since then it's garnered 149 views via Stumble.  That's over half its current view count.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking this as a one-suggestion-per-answer thing so people can up-vote. In deemed inappropriate, I'll merge my answers later.

[Experience for 'Role Playing'](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/146/experience-for-role-playing/170)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, it's possible to submit an RSS feed to Digg, which results in all new articles getting auto-submitted.

Comment: Well that takes all the fun out of it :P

Comment: It is also the case that the Digg front page has been taken over by spam and random crap, not entirely coincidentally. I think the question's still useful for Reddit and Stumbleupon!

Comment: Indeed! It seems Digg is having some tough times... reading [@Stefano Borini](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/113/stefano-borini)'s [blog](http://forthescience.org/blog/2010/08/30/fear-the-crowd-digg-4-spurs-users-revolt/) I heard about Digg users revolting by flooding it with links to its competitor Reddit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking this as a one-suggestion-per-answer thing so people can up-vote. In deemed inappropriate, I'll merge my answers later.

And definitely [Approaches to diceless (or lessened dice reliance) in RPGs](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/319/approaches-to-diceless-or-lessened-dice-reliance-in-rpgs)